# werneckbh/qr-code, can not generate .png QR image

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

I am using "werneckbh/qr-code", trying to generate an QR code and store it in a PDF file.

I installed all the dependencies.

For now i copied the route from their documentation site

https://werneckbh.github.io/laravel-qr-code/text.html

```
Route::get('qr-code/examples/text', function () 
{
    return  QRCode::text('Laravel QR Code Generator!')->png();   
});
```

but when I run it, all I get are just random characters, like on image bellow
[image]

when I use "svg" format it works ok, but I can not save "svg" image in a PDF file.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: That is the raw image data. You now need to save it to a file somewhere and call the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
Route::get('qr-code/examples/text', function () 
{
    return  QRCode::text('Laravel QR Code Generator!')
        ->setOutfile('/path/to/email-qr-code.png')
        ->png();   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this

```
public function qr_code()
{
   $qrCode = QRCode::text('Laravel QR Code Generator!')->png();
}
```

Just run the function, this will generate QR code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this

```
Route::get('qr-code', function () 
{
  $img = \QRCode::text('QR Code Generator for Laravel!')->png();   
  return response($img)->header('Content-type','image/png');
});
```